# Adding a skip to checkout button woocmmerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add another button beside "add to cart" on single product page that will add the product to cart and also take the user to checkout page .

if I will use

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

this will override the add to cart button, but I want it to be like it is and want another button that will do this job ? is it possible with hooks ?

Comment: Yes, create a function that adds the item to the basket and redirects to checkout automatically. `global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);`

Comment: @DanWhite thank you for your response, It will not work for variable products and group products .I do not have group [products but still would like to know if it can be done with out using javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using a hidden field and two submit button, May be a dirty way but it solved my problem. It can be done in a better way using a checkbox in place of two button,  *( if checkbox is checked go to checkout page ).

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_skip_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_variable_skip_to_checkout', 30 );
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_variable_skip_to_checkout' ) ) {

    function woocommerce_variable_skip_to_checkout() {
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variation-skip-to-checkout-button.php' );
    }
}
add_filter ('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', function() {
    if ( isset($_POST['skip_to_checkout']) && $_POST['skip_to_checkout'] == 'true' ){
        return WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();      
    }
} );
```

Template part

```
variation-skip-to-checkout-button.php
```

template holds the "skip to checkout" button and a hidden field, which you can replace with direct html in this function or a checkbox. and in place of `woocommerce_variable_skip_to_checkout` hook you should definitely prefer `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button` hook.

Comment: actually, if using a button tag, you don't need another hidden field. Just add a name and a value to your button. `<button type="submit" name="skip_to_checkout" value="true" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">skip to checkout</button>`. I also suggest to check if the product is purchasable. And have at least these classes. The classes are there for design and checking if purchasable for product variation.

Comment: @Reigel thank you for your suggestion about checking if purchasable and also for using only a button .I will update it.